# Prompt to continue in the app after specific link was clicked

Tags: swift

I'm working on the app that has an email confirmation for new users. The task I need to complete is that if user clicks on the activation link from the mail application it should show a prompt to continue activation the the app if one is installed. It's a similar behavior to the universal links but I need the redirection only for that specific case. All the other links should be opened normally in the browser. Does anyone has an idea how can I achieve this?

P.S. attached picture represent an expected behavior.

[image]

Comment: You can configure a universal link with a specific path to open the app, universal links don't necessarily have to work for the entire domain. Here's one of many tutorials on the web: https://medium.com/wolox/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/). Some reading material:

- https://www.raywenderlich.com/6080-universal-links-make-the-connection
- https://abhimuralidharan.medium.com/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272
- https://medium.com/wolox/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97

Comment: It's not really what I'm looking for as Universal Links don't provide an option to continue on the web. It automatically redirects on the to the app